# How to count the number of times a specific character appears in a text file, before another specific character?

Tags: c#, .net, text, count, character

Is there a way to count the number of times a specific character appears before another specific character, in a text file?

Lets say I have the following written in a text file: xxx*xxx~xxx*xxx*xxx~

I would like to count the number of times the character "*" appears before the "~" character, and do a new counting of "*" characters until the next "~" character and so on.

I would really appreciate some help here, thank you.

Comment: Since it's a pattern, I'd say `regex` may be the way to go with this.

Comment: If you don't feel like making some clever, complicated or advanced stuff, and you are a beginner in C#, why don't you read the text file character-by-character and just count? It might not be the fastest and most awesomest code, but shouldn't be too difficult to implement (and as imporant: easy to debug), no?

Comment: Could you give a more general input, or more life-like, if you wish?

Comment: Why not? Nothing in your question indicates what would work and what would not work, or what particular constraints prevent you from processing the text file on a character-by-character basis...

Comment: Your explanation does not explain why reading the file character-by-character and count would not work. Your explanation does not rule out character-by-character processing at all. Anyway, it is of course up to you what you like or don't like to do, or what is good or not so good in a certain scenario, but that's not the same as saying "_That wouldn't work in this scenario_"...

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int FindCountOfCharBeforeAnotherChar(string text, char find, char findBefore)
{
    var indexOfFindBefore = text.IndexOf(findBefore);
    if (indexOfFindBefore < 1) return 0;
    var textBeforeMatch = text.Substring(0, indexOfFindBefore);
    return textBeforeMatch.Count(c => c == find);
}

[TestCase("aXa", 1)]
[TestCase("aaXa", 2)]
[TestCase("aaa", 0)]
[TestCase("Xaa", 0)]
public void FindsExpectedCharacterCount(string text, int expected)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, FindCountOfCharBeforeAnotherChar(text, find:'a', findBefore:'X'));
}
```